# Ads being cutting off at the end

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, advertising

Just saw this on Code Review:

[image]

The asker's name is `Julian Hernandez` -- the last letter has been cut off. As has the very edge of the `S` in `PK_FILE_EXTENSIONS` (but that's because it's a big single word).

Can this be fixed? Why is it actually happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it actually happening?

The problem here is with `PK_FILE_EXTENSIONS` - it is one long word and it doesn't break, causing the width of the ad content to be wider than the width of the ad itself, cutting it.

> Can this be fixed?

Adding a style `word-break: break-word;` to the ad would do it. But the problem then is that where it break is arbitrary and it is unclear the word has been broken.

As something very rare, we won't fix the issue.

Comment: I get the problem with the title, so does that mean the author's name is relative to the size of the entire content? So if the content is bigger, the name is more to the right?

Comment: The author name is just a placed in an offset to the right of the container. That's why it got cut off.